# Jackson - converting java object to json - Need all key keys to upper case

Tags: java, json, object, jackson, uppercase

Need your help on conversion of java objects to json.
current the json result showing all the key in small letter case, i need it to be upper case.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Writer strWriter = new StringWriter();
mapper.writeValue(strWriter, obj);
String jsonString= strWriter.toString();
```

and the result is

```
[{"flags":"1","name":"Peter","location":"London","startDate":"2012-01-06 00:00"}]
```

but i want results like this (all key key value should be in UPPER CASE):

```
[{"FLAGS":"YU","NAME":"Peter","LOCATION":"London","STARTDATE":"2012-01-06 00:00"}]
```

and also is it possible to get like this also (key first letter in upper case):

```
[{"Flags":"1","Name":"Peter","Location":"London","StartDate":"2012-01-06 00:00"}]
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

There are multiple ways to do it with Jackson.

#### Annotations

You could annotate your object with `@JsonProperty` [annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations) on your fields or on your getter methods.

Example:

```
@JsonProperty("Name")
public final String name;

@JsonProperty("Location")
public String getLocation() {
  return location;
}
```

#### Implement JsonSerializableWithType interface

```
@Override
public void serialize(final JsonGenerator jG, final SerializerProvider p)
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
{
    serializeWithType(jG, p, null);
}

@Override
public void serializeWithType(final JsonGenerator jG, final SerializerProvider p, final TypeSerializer typeSer)
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
{
    // here you can do your own serialization
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advice to use the  `@JsonNaming` annotation on class level.

Yet afaik there is no strategy out there to fit your needs for total uppercase. But you can probably just write your own.

In my case I needed first character uppercase. So I used the existing
`@JsonNaming(value = UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)`.