# Android: Convert object to JSON string

Tags: android, json, serialization, jackson

I am using [Android SpringRest](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android) with [Jakson](http://jackson.codehaus.org). Currently I am using:

```
restTemplate.postForObject(baseURL + url, 
                           postCarDetail, 
                           ReplyToAdResponse.class, 
                           auth_token);
```

Now I want to check if everything in the `postCarDetail` object is in the correct format. How can I convert this `postCarDetail` into a JSON string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6339454/180100 might help

Comment: no, dont want to read from a file, just convert my object to a json string.

Comment: found it out here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049174/jackson-converting-java-object-to-json-need-all-key-keys-to-upper-case